# requireJS and node modules. How to require?

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I need my application to send emails, so I came across nodemailer, easy and fast solution. Tried it and after a `node app.js` the email was sent. Great.

Now, I want my web app to send emails, and since `require` is not defined in browser-side I ended up reading about `browserify`, `commonJS` and finally `requireJS`.

Tried it for simple `.js` files and it seems to be pretty much straight forward. Right now I'm stucked in the process of making it work with the folder node_modules that stores my `nodemailer` module.

How can I do that? In the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) it says that I shouldn't `require("./node_modules/foo/foo").` so how can I `require` my module? I couldn't find any complete example of this.

The structure of my app's relevant files is something like this.

**`Project/index.html`  ***
**`Project/js/app.js`**`//my own mvc app.js, not requireJS's`
**`Project/js/mailer.js`**`//.js that holds the nodemailer code for sending emails`
**`Project/node_modules/requirejs`**`//requirejs.js inside`
**`Project/node_modules/nodemailer`**`//nodemailer module`

### Update

#### (since it's taking my whole day)

I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Script error for: nodemailer` It can't find the `nodemailer.js` file. It's looking for it in the root directoy. Why? Doesn't `requireJS` look for it inside node_modules?

#### Index.html

```
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    data-main="main"
    src="./node_modules/requirejs/require.js">
</script>
```

#### Main.js

```
var nodemailer = require(["nodemailer"],
    function(nodemailer){
            //email code
    }
);
```

Any idea what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't waste your time, you can't send mail from browser. nodemailer is supposed to run in node as the name implies.

Comment: @vkurchatkin do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Set up node.js server and use nodemailer acсording to documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand that a browser has a specific set of capabilities, and directly sending email is not one of them. Browserify can only make a very limited set of simple nodejs modules runnable inside the browser, but it can't magically make the browser able to read arbitrary files, make arbitrary network connections, do DNS lookups, and other stuff that have been explicitly added to node to make it into a server environment. There is some misleading browserify documentation around this, but no you cannot take an arbitrary node module, run it through browserify, and use it in the browser. You will need to do something along the lines of:

- Use a good old `<a href="mailto:...">` link
- make an ajax request to the server and have the server send a mail on behalf of the browser

Comment: Ok, I missundertood the concept of `require` then. Your second guessing seems fine. All I should do is set up a node server and get my code executed via ajax right?

Comment: Right. Code in your node app can use node-mailer to send email, and you can trigger this by having browser code make an AJAX request to your server.